# How do i "merge" two ranges into one in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have two ranges. One that includes A1:A3 and one that includes A4:A6.
How do I merge them into a new range that includes A1:A6 ?

Comment: Perhaps using `Union`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use UNION - as BigBen suggested

```vb
Public Function joinTwoRanges(rg1 As Range, rg2 As Range) As Range

    Dim rgNew As Range
    Set rgNew = Union(rg1, rg2)
    
    Set joinTwoRanges = rgNew

End Function
```

Comment: I want to use the new range (created by using Union) (A1:A6) in a sumproduct with another range containing 6 rows (B1:B6). But when using sumproduct i get #VALUE. It seems like the range i get from using Union only have 3 rows? I would expect 6?

Comment: How do you use SUMPRODUCT? The joined range returns two areas, that means that you have to check both areas to count for the rows. BUT: why aren't you using a range A1:B6 in your formula? - No need to have this extra routine.